# How to deal with complex schema in SQL database

Tags: sql, database

can anyone please help to create a query for this, I tried a lot but did not succeed

create a SQL query selecting all employees, invoice totals for the customers they handle.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it?

Comment: I need EmployeeId and sum of invoices for each customers which is in support of employee, supporterripid in customer table is same as Employee id in Employee table

Comment: output look like this https://www.mediafire.com/view/76cnoigmwruebvl/bbb.png/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a single invoice is calculated by `UnitPrice * Quantity`, the following query should work:

```
select EmployeeId, sum(invoice) InvoicesTotal
from 
    (select EmployeeId, SupportRepId, CustomerId
    from employees e 
    left join customers c
    on e.EmployeeId = c.SupportRepId) ec
left join 
    (select CustomerId, sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) invoice
    from invoices i
    join
    invoice_items ii
    on i.InvoiceId = ii.InvoiceId 
    group by CustomerId) ci
on 
    ec.CustomerId = ci.CustomerId
group by EmployeeId
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly

Comment: Is it possible to order the result set in descending order by the total invoice sum

Comment: Yes, you can add `order by 2 desc` at the bottom of the query